# クロージャー内部で生成させたUIImageを、クロージャー外部で使うにはどうしたらいいですか？

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode7, swift2

swift及びプログラミング初心者です。
スタンプカメラアプリでカメラロールに保存したUIImageをTwitter投稿させる機能の実装方法で悩んでいます。
撮影ボタンを押すとクロージャー内部で画像を合成させて、最終的にcapturedImage2というUIImageが生成させました。
(カメラロールには画像が保存できています)
以下、クロージャー内部のコードです。

```
let myAVConnection = myImageOutPut.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
myImageOutPut.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(myAVConnection, completionHandler: 
    {(imageDataBuffer, error) -> Void in
        ・・・・
        ・・・・
        ・省略・
        ・・・・
        ・・・・
        let capturedImage2: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(capturedImage2, self, nil, nil)
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    })
}
```

クロージャ内部で生成したcapturedImage2をtwitterに投稿したいため、Socialフレームワークを用いて以下の様なコードを記述したいと思っています。

```
@IBAction func postTwitter(sender: AnyObject) {
    let twVC:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)!
    let sendImage = rarara
    twVC.addImage(sendImage)
    self.presentViewController(twVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

上記のコードで
`let sendImage = rarara`
右辺のrararaの部分をクロージャ内部で生成したUIImageであるcapturedImage2としたいのですが、記述方法が分かりません。
クロージャ内部で生成したものをクロージャ外部で使いたい場合、どういったコーディングをすべきなのでしょうか。

Comment: エディターの中に{}で表示されるコード挿入機能があったはずなので、そちらを使うか(ヘルプ等で表示されているはずですが)手動で4桁空白を挿入するなどして、コード部分を見やすく整形するよう心がけてください。また、「省略」される部分にたくさんの行数を費やして目立たせる必要はないと思います。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*クロージャ内部で生成したものをクロージャ外部で使いたい場合、どういったコーディングをすべきなのでしょうか。*
クロージャー内部で生成したものはクロージャー内部で使う、と言うのが(とりわけそのクロージャーが非同期処理の完了ハンドラであるなら)コーディングの基本です。

```
let myAVConnection = myImageOutPut.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
myImageOutPut.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(myAVConnection, completionHandler: {(imageDataBuffer, error) -> Void in
    //省略...
    let capturedImage2: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(capturedImage2, self, nil, nil)
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    //ここでは、captureImage2に確実に必要なUIImageが入っているのだから、それを使うコードはここに書く
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        let twVC:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)!
        let sendImage = capturedImage2
        twVC.addImage(sendImage)
        self.presentViewController(twVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
})
```

どうしても別メソッドとしたいので、あればクロージャーの内部からそのメソッドを呼べば良いだけです。(ついでに少しでも短くするために末尾クロージャー用の省略表記を使わせてもらいます。)

```
    let myAVConnection = myImageOutPut.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    myImageOutPut.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(myAVConnection) {imageDataBuffer, error in
        //省略...
        let capturedImage2: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(capturedImage2, self, nil, nil)
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        //ここでは、captureImage2に確実に必要なUIImageが入っているのだから、それを使うコードはここに書く
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.sendToTwitter(capturedImage2)
        }
    }
```

(上のメソッドとは別のメソッドに。)

```
func sendToTwitter(rarara: UIImage) {
    let twVC:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)!
    let sendImage = rarara
    twVC.addImage(sendImage)
    self.presentViewController(twVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

撮影ボタンを押したときに投稿するのであれば、postTwitter()メソッドのように@IBActionを想定したメソッドにする必要はないように思います。

細部の動作までは未確認ですので、それでは要件に合う動作とならないとか、実行時に変なエラーが出るとかいった可能性もあるかと思いますが、その場合はコメント等で内容を詳しくお知らせください。

(補足)captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler:の完了ハンドラはメインスレッドで呼ばれるとは限らないのでコード例を一部修正しました。

(追記)コメントに頂いたように「撮影ボタンを押してTwitterに投稿したい人のみTwitter投稿ボタンを押して投稿してい‌​ただく仕様」と言うことであれば例えばこのようにコーディング出来る、と言うのをあげておきます。ポイントは、

- 撮影されたイメージをどこか適当な場所に保持しておく
- イメージの準備ができたことを通知して、画面(UI)に反映させる

の2点でしょうか。

```
//撮影が完了したイメージをインスタンスプロパティとして保持しておくようにする
var postedImage: UIImage? = nil
//ツイッターボタン(初期状態はenabledをfalseにしておく)
@IBOutlet weak var twitterButton: UIButton!
```

ここでは、イメージを保持する場所は該当ViewControllerのインスタンスプロパティ、イメージの準備ができていることはツイッターボタンのenabledプロパティに反映させる、といった仕様を仮定しておきます。画面の構成によってはイメージを保存する場所は、AppDelegateの方が良いかもしれませんし、専用のデータ保持用クラスを定義してしまう方が良い場合もあります。

撮影時の処理は以下のようになるでしょう。

```
    let myAVConnection = myImageOutPut.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    myImageOutPut.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(myAVConnection) {imageDataBuffer, error in
        //省略...
        let capturedImage2: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(capturedImage2, self, nil, nil)
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        //ここでは、captureImage2に確実に必要なUIImageが入っているのだから、それを使うコードはここに書く
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            //取得したイメージをどこかに保存
            self.postedImage = capturedImage2
            //self.postedImageの準備ができたことを何らかの方法で知らせる
            self.twitterButton.enabled = true
        }
    }
```

ここでは、ツイッターボタンが押されたら、もうそのイメージは利用できないよということにしておきます。

```
@IBAction func postTwitter(sender: UIButton) {
    let twVC:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)!
    //次のイメージが撮影されるまでボタンを使えないようにする
    sender.enabled = false
    if let sendImage = postedImage {
        postedImage = nil
        twVC.addImage(sendImage)
        self.presentViewController(twVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        //ボタンのenabledが正しく制御されていればここは通らないはずだが、念のためログくらいは出力する
        NSLog("Twitter button pressed while postedImage == nil")
    }
}
```

いかがでしょうか。何かお気付きの点がありましたら、またご連絡ください。

Comment: 撮影ボタンを押したときにTwitterに投稿するという仕様ではなく、撮影ボタンを押してTwitterに投稿したい人のみTwitter投稿ボタンを押して投稿していただく仕様を考えております。Twitterに投稿したくない人もいると思ったため、クロージャー外部にpostTwitter()メソッドを用意するコーディングを考えておりました。アドバイス頂いたコードでエラーもなく動作致しました。加えまして、私自身初心者すぎてこちらのサイトにも慣れていないため、質問欄の使い方に不備があった点、申し訳ありません。

Comment: 掲載しましたコードに大きなエラーがないことをご報告いただきまして助かります。サイトの使い方については正直自分もヘルプ等の内容をよく読みながら使っているのが実際のところなので、追々(その必要がなければその方が良いのですが)慣れていかれればと思います。コメントに記載された仕様なら自分ならどうするかというのを追記しておきます。どの程度使い物になるかわかりませんが、ご確認いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 追記のコードとてもありがたいです。撮影ボタンを押した後、さらにTwitterボタンを押してはじめてpresentViewController()メソッドが読まれるという動作を確認いたしました。オプショナルバインディングを使って実装するという発想もなかったので勉強になりました。